# probability that x number of bits are corrupted in an n-bit data unit

Tags: probability

Assume that the probability that a bit in a data unit is corrupted during transmission is p. Find the probability that x number of bits are corrupted in an n-bit data unit for each of the following cases: (a) n=8, x=1, p=0.2 (b) n=16, x=0, p=0.1, (c) n=32, x>0, p=0.05.

Comment: Dear user1836056, I do not appreciate seeing my questions reproduced on the internet.  Yours sincerely, Your Tutor.

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly a question about binomial distributions.  This should probably be helpful:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution